MSAL acquireTokenSilent makes new request everytime, cache is ignored
@azure/msal-browser 3.20.0
@azure/msal-react: 2.0.22
I have SPA react client app, and API on backend.
I made two App registrations, exposed custom api, consented as admin.
Everything works, i successfully get 200 ok message from my protected API.
At some point i noticed that calling instance.acquireTokenSilent results in making request to MS everytime, while it is supposed to use token stored in cache.
Tokens received in these redundant calls are obviously the same as the one already stored in cache, since that token is still valid
This is my custom scope


export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["api://my-guid/tasks.read"]
    forceRefresh: false
};



Looking into cache, the scope is saved there in property target, and the value is the same

api://my-guid/tasks.read

.
What i noticed though, is that when i decrypt the access token manually, besides other claims, i get
"scp": "tasks.read"

which is stripped of the api:://guid/ part, i dont know if this could be the reason, but i find it suspicious at least.
I found several similar topics such as this one but that is a known issue for b2c, plus the solution is to use custom scope, which i already use.
Other solutions suggested to call acquireTokenSilent per each scope separately, but i only use single scope so that should not be the problem either.
msalConfig


export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "client-guid",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-guid",
        redirectUri: "https://localhost:5173/",
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge     
    },
}




If acquireTokenSilent in your React SPA client app is making unnecessary requests to Microsoft, it might be due to a mismatch between the scopes requested and the scopes stored in the cache, incorrect cache configuration, or improper use of the acquireTokenSilent method. Ensure that the scope is requested without the api:// prefix, as MSAL normalizes the scope name in the cache. Verify that the cache configuration and acquireTokenSilent method usage are correct, and enable verbose logging in MSAL to gain insight into the issue.

Additionally, check the app registration setup and the MSAL version for any bugs or known issues.

After investigating further, i found out that i was calling the acquireTokenSilent with incorrect parameters. I was actually passing object with two props. The request prop was holding object with the scopes prop

request:object
account:account

previous call
const tokenResponse = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({ request: accessTokenRequest, account: accounts[0] });  

correct, working call
const tokenResponse = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({...accessTokenRequest, account: accounts[0]});

while accessTokenRequest is
export const accessTokenRequest = {
    scopes: ["api://my-app-guid/tasks.read"], 
    forceRefresh: false
};

What was very missleading though, was the fact that the requests to API actually went through, passed the authorize attribute. The only thing that didnt work was the cache.
